# How to get specific area object of an array in php?

Tags: php

I am generating a Bitcoin address using bit coin API. Bit coin API's variable returns full array ,how i get only "available_balance" part.
This part only:

```
[available_balance] => 0.00138592
```

**Code is:**

```
$data=$block_io->get_address_balance(array('type' => 'received', 'addresses' => '3KHBGTRGFEgRHub8z5VUyT9L5ZUASpWZ'));

function pr($data)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($data); // or var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";
}

pr($data);
```

Output is:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => success
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [network] => BTC
            [available_balance] => 0.00138592
            [pending_received_balance] => 0.00000000
            [balances] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [user_id] => 5
                            [label] => Lalaa
                            [address] => 3KHBGTRGFEgRHub8z5VUyT9L5ZUASpWZ
                            [available_balance] => 0.00138592
                            [pending_received_balance] => 0.00000000
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$res_arr=array();
foreach($data->data->balances as $value) {
    $res_arr[] =$value->available_balance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$stdClass->data->balances[0]->available_balance`

Is how you get the value

Or if you want the outer level one you do this:

`$stdClass->data->available_balance`